# Tig doesn't show lines but instead ~T~B (or similiar)

Tags: tig

I am using tig to view git history but the interface is not showing the lines any longer, see picture.

I'm sadly on a Windows environment running git bash. Does anyone know how I can get the lines instead?

[image: tig error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to change the "graphics" configuration to something your system supports.

Hit `~` until you see something you like; You'll see something in the statusbar that looks like `set line-graphics = utf-8`.

Then edit your `$HOME/.gitconfig` and add a that line-graphics value to a tig section:

```
[tig]
  line-graphics = utf-8
```